# Weasyprint pdf generation, too long, makes the download impossible. How to stream its creation?

Tags: python, django, weasyprint

I've been using Weasyprint for pdf generation successfully, until I reach a certain size, a common use case of my app, where the pdf generation takes so long (more than 10s) that it breaks the connectivity with the browser, and the download is impossible.

I suppose I must stream the file creation and return a django [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-large-csv-files) (agree ?). I wouldn't pre-process the pdf because it is formed from baskets with items users frequently add or delete.

But **how can I stream the file creation** with [weasyprint](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#instantiating-html-and-css-objects) ? Even if I cut my sourceHtml string in parts, how to write the pdf step by step ?

I render a django template and generate the pdf from it:

```
from weasyprint import HTML

sourceHtml = template.render(my-objects)
outhtml = HTML(string=sourceHtml).write_pdf()

response = HttpResponse(outhtml, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = u'attachment; filename="{}.pdf"'.format(name)
```

Or is there another way to solve this problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: A browser can wait for response without any time limit. If your connection breaks that means timeout is set somwhere in your web server or reverse proxy. Just find where it is and increase it.

Comment: @YaroslavStavnichiy that may not fix the pb but that may make way more use cases work. Though it would be great users wait while a file is downloading rather than when a spinner is looping. Thanks for the hint !

Answer (score 1):

I asked on the issue tracker: https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/416

It is not doable and a suggested workaround is to

> split the download into two steps: one route asynchronously generates the document and stores it on the filesystem, the second route downloads the generated document. When the document is not generated yet, you can hide the second link and display something like "the document is not generated yet" instead.