# Django weasyprint HTML to PDF convert is working very slow

Tags: python, django, pdf, django-models, weasyprint

I am covering HTML to PDF file using weasyprint in Django web app. Everything is working fine but It is working is very slow when converting HTML to PDF. It takes more than two minutes long When I convert it.
I am using Bangla font in my HTML file.

this is my **views.py** code

```
def get_pdf_file(request, customer_id, sys_type):
    sys_type = customer_id
    area = "pdf"
    site_credit = site_credit1
    time_now = timezone.now()
    customers = get_object_or_404(CustomerInfo, pk=customer_id)




    due_taka_track = customers.duetaka_set.all()

    if due_taka_track == None:
        due_taka_track = 0

    unpaid_taka = int(customers.customer_price -
                      customers.customer_due_taka_info)
    due_taka_track = customers.duetaka_set.all()

    sum_cost_taka = due_taka_track.aggregate(
        sp=Sum('customer_due')).get('sp', 0)

    if sum_cost_taka == None:
        sum_cost_taka = 0
    total_paid_taka = sum_cost_taka + customers.customer_due_taka_info

    payment_status = 'complete'
    payment_message = 'Full Paid'
    remain_taka='PAID'
    remain_msg=''

    if customers.customer_due_taka_info < customers.customer_price:
        payment_status = 'incomplete'
        payment_message = 'সম্পূর্ন টাকা পরিষোধ করা হয়নি'
        remain_msg='টাকা বাকী আছে'
        baki_ase="পাওনা আছে "

        remain_taka = customers.customer_price - customers.customer_due_taka_info



    context = {'customers': customers,
    'sys_type': sys_type,
    'area': area,
    'site_credit': site_credit,
    'site_name': 'Moon Telecom',
    'sys_type': sys_type,
    'due_taka_track': due_taka_track,
    'total_paid_taka': total_paid_taka,
    'payment_message': payment_message,
    'time_now': time_now,
    'unpaid_taka': unpaid_taka,
    'payment_message': payment_message,
    'remain_taka': remain_taka,
    'sum_cost_taka': sum_cost_taka,
    'remain_msg': remain_msg}

    html_string = render_to_string('shop/pdf_invoice.html', context)
    html = HTML(string=html_string)
    result = html.write_pdf()

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf;')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=invoice'+sys_type+'.pdf'
    response['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'UTF-8'
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True) as output:
        output.write(result)
        output.flush()
        output = open(output.name, 'rb')
        response.write(output.read())

    return response
```

**This is my HTML file. This file I am convering HTML to PDF**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Moon Telecom</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.maateen.me/kalpurush/font.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>

        p,
        td,
        tr {
            font-size: 10px;
            line-height: 12px;
        }

        body {
            font-family: 'Kalpurush', Arial, sans-serif !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="site_title" style="text-align:center; margin:0 auto">
                    <p style="font-size:15px">মুন টেলিকম</p>

                    <div class="invoice_info_one" style="width:100%; text-align:center">
                        <p>সকল প্রকার মোবাইল সেট, সীম কার্ড, মেমোরী কার্ড, MP-3, সোলার চার্জার, সোলার ফ্যান, মোবাইল ফোনের ব্যাটারী,
                            চার্জার, ক্যাচিং,কাভার,হেডফোন, রেবন, ডিসপ্লে এবং ইলেট্রিক মালামাল বিক্রেতা</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="invoice_location">
                        <p>জাহাঙ্গীর সুপার মার্কেট, ব্রীজ রোড, ফুলহাতা বাজার, মোডেলগঞ্জ।</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="invoice_contact">
                        <p>01717-051200(সুকান্ত) 01828-163858(দোকান)</p>
                        <p>
                            <b>Email:</b> moontelecom2008@gmail.com</p>
                    </div>



                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">

                <div class="customer_info">
                    {% if customers.customer_name %}
                    <p style="font-size:15px">Customer Name:
                        <b> {{customers.customer_name}}</b>
                        <span style="color:red">{{customers.customer_first_due_info}}</span>
                    </p>
                    {% else %}
                    <p> Name: দেওয়া হয়নি</p> {% endif %}

                    <p style="font-size:14px">Phone Number: {% if customers.customer_mobile_no %} {{customers.customer_mobile_no}} {% else %} No Mobile
                        Number {% endif %}
                    </p>
                    <p style="font-size:14px">Purchase Time: {{customers.customer_sell_date}}</p>
                    <p style="font-size:14px">invoice id:
                        <b>{{customers.customer_uid}}</b>
                    </p>
                    <p>{{customers.product_warrenty}}</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="customer_product_and_paid_info">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Product Name</th>
                                    <th colspan="">Price</th>
                                    <th>ID or IME</th>
                                    <th>Warrenty</th>
                                    <th>QN</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <b>{{customers.customer_product_name}}</b>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <b>{{customers.customer_price}}</b> TK
                                        <i>{% if customers.customer_discount_taka %} Discount added TK: {{customers.customer_discount_taka}}
                                            TK {% else %} {% endif %}</i>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{customers.customer_product_id}}</td>


                                    <td>
                                        {% if customers.customer_product_warrenty %} {{customers.customer_product_warrenty}} Months {% else %} No {% endif %}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{customers.customer_product_quantity}}</td>
                                </tr>


                                <th>
                                    <hr> First Time Payment</th>
                                <th>

                                    <hr> {{customers.customer_first_time_payment}} TK
                                    <span style="color:red">{{customers.customer_first_due_info}}</span>
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                    <hr> {{customers.customer_sell_date}}
                                </td>


                                {% if due_taka_track %}


                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>SL</th>
                                        <th>Taka</th>
                                        <th>Paid Date</th>
                                        <td>Due Info</td>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <hr> {% for track in due_taka_track %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <i>{{track.customer_due}}</i> TK</td>
                                        <td>{{track.customer_due_date}}</td>
                                        <td>{{track.customer_due_info}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </tbody>


                                {% else %} {% endif %} {% if sum_cost_taka %}
                                <tr>

                                    <td>Total Due Complete </td>

                                    <th>{{sum_cost_taka}} TK</th>

                                </tr>
                                {% else %} {% endif %}





                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <b>Total Paid</b>
                                    </td>

                                <th>


                                    {% if payment_message %} 

                                    {{customers.customer_due_taka_info}} TK

                                    <span style="color:red">{{payment_message}}</span>
                                    <br>

                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">{{remain_msg}} {{remain_taka}} TK</button>
                                    {%else %} 

                                    {{customers.customer_due_taka_info}} TK
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Payment Completed</button>

                                    {% endif %}
                                </th>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="customer_notifications">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">

                    {% if customers.customer_conditions %}
                    <div class="warning">
                        <p style="font-size:8px; width:500px;line-height:15px;">
                            <i>{{customers.customer_product_name}} {{customers.customer_conditions}}</i>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    {% else %} {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>








    <div class="footer" style="display:block">
        <div class="footer_info">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="footer_info">
                            <p>Print date: {{time_now}}</p>
                            <p>
                                <b>বিঃদ্রঃ ডেলিভারির সময় মাল বুঝিয়া নিবেন। পরে কোন আপত্তী গ্রহনযোগ্য নয়</b>
                            </p>
                            <p>বিক্রিত মাল ফেরত নেওয়া হয় না</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="copy_right">
                            {% if site_credit %}
                            <p>{{site_credit}}</p>
                            {% else %}

                            {% endif %}

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I'm no expert in this arena, but here's an alternate method I use. Maybe try this for a speed comparison? http://www.peregrinesalon.com/blog/2015/06/python-3-django-generating-a-pdf-from-markdown-or-html/

Comment: See also the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41723844/5320906